# How to add vertical menu items to Bootstrap popover?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, menu, bootstrap-popover

I'm using **Bootstrap v3.3.5** in my website. 
I want to open-up a popover which contains three menu items separated by horizontal lines.

Menu items should be vertical and should be as follows :

- Edit Event
- Invite Members
- Delete Event

Each of the menu items should be hyperlink to open-up some new modal dialog or something like that.
For it I tried below code but it didn't work out for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <a href="#" data-toggle="popover">Toggle popover</a>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();   
});
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to do it with popover only? Cant you use drop-down for your requirement?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Something like this should work, here is a [JsFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/gnLn2cnr/).

Here I have utilised an existing `Bootstrap` component, a list-group as an example but you can put any `HTML` into your popover:

#### HTML

```
<!-- body content -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title">Toggle popover</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- loaded popover content -->
<ul id="popover-content" class="list-group" style="display: none">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Edit Event</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Invite Members</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Delete Event</a>
</ul>
```

#### jQuery

```
$(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        html: true,
        content: function() {
            return $('#popover-content').html();
        }
  });
});
```

A very useful library which works great with `Bootstrap` and will likely aid you in your efforts to create asynchronous calls like inline editing, is [X-Editable](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/)

Comment: X-Editable plugin found very handy. Thanks :)